# Ansible command wont output as playbook

Tags: powershell, ansible, azure-powershell

Im using ansible 2.7.5 and a windows 10 host over winRM.

If I execute:

```
ansible win -I hosts -m win_command -a "PowerShell.exe ipconfig"
```

I get an output and it works fine.

But I want to write it inside a playbook and not as an ansible command but I won't get any output so I tried to use stdout but it wont work:

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: PowerShell Command
    win_command: powershell.exe
    register: shell_result
    args: 
      stdin: ipconfig
      -debug: 
         var: shell_result.stdout_lines
```

Any suggestions how to get the first command working as a playbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `- debug` task isn't indented properly and doesn't have the right spacing. I'm not sure if that's just from posting here or if it's in your original file.

Your call to `powershell.exe` left out the `-` parameter which is what tells it to accept input on stdin. So it should be `win_command: powershell.exe -`.

That said, `ipconfig` is actually `ipconfig.exe` so instead of trying to run a shell with `win_command` just run `ipconfig.exe` directly:

```
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: ipconfig
    win_command: ipconfig.exe
    register: shell_result
  - debug: 
      var: shell_result.stdout_lines
```